# How to access method in eloquent model of current user

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Everything what I was searching tells me about `Auth::user()` or `auth()->user()` but it gives access to result of query to DB - to all fields of record.

Here are details.
Laravel 8.x
There is eloquent model called `User`. I created also another elo model `Example`. There is relation in database one-to-one so table `examples` has foreign key `user_id`. In `User` model I created
`public function example() { return $this->hasOne(); }`
and in Example:
`public function user() { $this->belongsTo(); }`

Now I have `ExampleController` with `public function __contruct()` - if current user doesnt have related example yet I want to run view to create it.

Tell me please what is a correct way to do that - to access current user model method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an inline middleware

```php
use App\Models\Example;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');

        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            if ( Example::where('user_id', Auth::id())->doesntExist() ) { 
                return redirect('user-has-no-example');
            }

            return $next($request);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use middleware in controler when I already did in my routes/web.php for each url that heads to that controller? (or maybe is it a good practice?)

My app is a part of jetstream.
Thats one of the routes:
`Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])
    ->post('example/something', [App\Http\Controllers\ExampleController::class, 'method'])
    ->name('example.name');`

So i thought I can use just `if (Auth::user()->example()->exists() ) { return view('create'); }` but it wont work, method `example()` isn'r recognized even with `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Comment: It's not necessary if you already did in routes. I just put the auth middleware because my solution requires an authenticated user.

Comment: Auth::class->user() is an object that represents authenticated user as a row from database. Its not same object as eloquent model of User so its not possible to access this method that way.

Comment: So your guard provider is set to use the database driver in `auth.php`? In that case Try `if ( Example::where('user_id', Auth::id())->doesntExist() )`

Comment: yup this is way I did that.